# HDF Object Package method unavailable

Tags: java, hdf5, hdf

Working on creating an .h5 parser for a project. Attempting to implement this tutorial code [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/hdf-java/hdf-java-examples/object/hdf5/H5DatasetRead.java). I'm running into an issue

```
Group root = (Group) ((javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode) testFile.getRootNode()).getUserObject();
```

where the getRootNode method is not recognized. Looking through the decompiled jar, the method doesn't exist where it should, despite being in the [javadocs](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/hdf-java/current/javadocs/hdf/object/FileFormat.html#getRootNode--). Where am I going wrong here? Is my HDFView jar that contains the relevant classes the wrong version or something?

Thanks for your input.